# Does ruby have a zip function like python's?

Tags: python, ruby, arrays

I am a newibe from python to ruby.

In python there is a feature like the following:

```
a=range(3)
b=range(3)
for e1,e2 in zip(a,b)
    print e1,e2
```

Is there something that can achieve the same function in ruby?

Comment: @Nakilon - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: Yes, Ruby does, only we call it "`zip`".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is what [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002198) does:

```
foo = [1,2,3,4]
bar = ['a','b','c','d']

foo.zip(bar) #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002198)?